# Typescript compiles class with unimplemented inherited abstract members

Tags: typescript, inheritance, abstract-class, abstract

Consider the following TS example:

```js
abstract class Abst {
    abstract get test(): string;
}

class Conc1 extends Abst {
    get test(): string { return 'ok'; }
}

class Conc2 extends Abst {   // <- this is in my perspective broken
}

console.log('???');
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgguRBvAsAFAIkKiQzwIDmApohLZABQCUAXAhQJYB21AbiIBfIijQYAwgHtesAIwJaAD0a8AJhmyQEBYqToMmENpx79dCKPQCuUXggDk0gNaOBCUYS-j0CGXIATEqqtBpaOLoiYrJg0si0AHTI0tTMjgD8WY6sQoRAA)

Apparently typescript compiles that code perfectly fine. In case of the playground it shows an error(!!) but it still compiles and runs. In case of the current project I'm working on, I don't even get those warnings for some reason (the IDE does show a warning though).

Why does this happen? The whole point of abstract methods is to specifically signal that they need to be implemented.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem here is, other than possibly some kind of misconfiguration of the project. The error in the playground and IDE *is* the error you're looking for. That's telling you to fix the issue, before you run it. The compiler is happy to emit JS even in the face of such errors, unless you enable [the `--noEmitOnError` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noEmitOnError). (more...)

Comment: (...continued) If you want to enable that so that it doesn't produce JS you can, but such config is not a problem with TS. Did that clear things up? If not, one of us is still confused so maybe you could [edit] to elaborate on exactly what you expected to see different.

Comment: @jcalz my expectation here was that missing symbols in a strongly typed language (which typescript aims to be) should be critical enough to not allow compilation. In the case above, for example, I'm saying the method *must* return a string, and yet the compiler generates *something* that definitely won't return a string and will definitely break.
I'll consider adopting that switch you mentioned, but in principle I just don't get how the compiler happily outputs something that is clearly wrong.

Comment: By the way, PHP (when such a broken class is defined), Kotlin and C# AFAIK would all have failed compilation in such a case.

Comment: Also regarding the cli switch, good to know...maybe consider writing that all into an answer?

Comment: I see someone already posted an answer mentioning that switch so I don't know if I have anything additional to say in an answer.  Maybe it would help to think of TS type checker errors as *warnings*, since they do not (by default) prevent compilation. The type checker and the JS emitter are independent, intentionally. The type system is fully erased from the emitted JS, so there's no confusion about what to emit, even in the face of type warnings.  Anyway I guess there's not much point in continuing here, since the question is answered and language-design philosophy is probably not in scope.

Comment: I was also quite interested in the language-design aspect... as I hinted in the last line of the question, where I find abstract symbols pointless if not enforced by the compiler. But anyway, I'll just keep the details you mentioned in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler (tsc) generates JavaScript output files per default whenever possible and even if the code still has compiler errors such as `Non-abstract class 'Conc2' does not implement all abstract members of 'Abst'` in this case.
Since JavaScript does not have `abstract` classes the output code can be run perfectly fine.

---

[No Emit On Error -
noEmitOnError](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noEmitOnError)

There is a tsc compiler option that alters this behavior: `"noEmitOnError": true`.

This prevents the compiler from emitting compiler output (JS code files, source maps, declaration files) if any errors were reported.

> This defaults to false, making it easier to work with TypeScript in a
> watch-like environment where you may want to see results of changes to
> your code in another environment before making sure all errors are
> resolved.

Comment: On a final note, do you know anything that could be causing the error not to show up? I've enabled that option in my project, but it still compiles.

Comment: Actually, never mind it, seems to be some crap with `webpack-dev-server` command - this problem is only happening in dev.

Comment: Unexpected compilation and *not showing up* are very different things. Former probably has its cause in some misconfiguration of your project. Latter is likely an issue with your IDE.

Comment: I meant not showing up in the IDE console output - the IDE is just running a command specified in package.json (which turns out to be the webpack stuff mentioned earlier). I'll dig in the webpack config.